# doctrine decimal not persisting in query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine

I've been having a problem with persisting a decimal with doctrine in my Symfony project.

I have a 'Proyectos' entity with a price among the variables, all variables are sent to the query without problem but price (which is a decimal) shows as null in the query and since in my SQL table price can't be null, an error appears.

The problem is somewhere between in query generation because in the form, "precio" is sent as decimal.

I've already tried changing the variable in the entity to number type without success.

Entity:

```
 /**
 * @var decimal
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="precio", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
 */
 private $precio;
```

In the table the field "precio" is decimal(10,2)

Controller:

```
$formBuilder = $this->get('form.factory')->createBuilder(FormType::class, $project);

$formBuilder
    ->add('titulo',         TextType::class)
    ->add('thumbdesc',      TextType::class)
    ->add('descripcion',    TextareaType::class)
    ->add('img',            TextType::class)
    ->add('thumbimg',       TextType::class)
    ->add('precio',         NumberType::class, array('scale' => 2))
    ->add('crear',          SubmitType::class);

$form = $formBuilder->getForm();

if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($project);
        $em->flush();

        $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Annonce bien enregistrée.');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('sofimar_inversiones_view', array('id' => $project->getId()));
    }
}
```

> Error:`SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'precio' cannot be null`

There must be some confusion between doctrine and symfony variable types but I just can't find the error.

Full error:

```
An exception occurred while executing
'INSERT INTO proyectos (titulo, descripcion, thumbdesc, thumbimg, img, precio, fecha)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
with params ["title", "description", "desc", "image", "img", null, "2017-06-25 16:39:48"]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'precio' cannot be null
```

And post parameters:

```
[titulo => title,
thumbdesc => desc,
descripcion => description,
img => img, thumbimg => image,
precio => 12.36, crear => ,
_token => qNaO1AD3BpqSOuTW2vdQz5pX4A4Pk2S3QNv6ZEhZmzo]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="precio", type="decimal", precision=10, scale=2)
 */
 private $precio;
```

And in form builder

```
->add('precio', NumberType::class, array('scale' => 2, 'required' => true))
```

Comment: didn't work, still having the same problem, still thanks for helping

Comment: Can you print an example of data sended by your form?